# Get the All Infromation of SharePoint Server using Client Object Model

Tags: web-services, com

I want to Create a Windows Application that

- Displays all Web Applications
- Sites Collection of Each web Application
- Sites of Each Site Collection
- Sub-Sites of Each Site
- All lists-Libraries of Each Site and Sub-Sites in Tree-view

But I don't want to Give any Static URL, on Application Start up That All Information Filled Automatically in Tree-view if SharePoint is Installed on that Computer.

Is this Possible (using Web services for example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your subject says, you want everything in client object model.
If yes, then as per my view, you must have to add some URL to find all sites/subsites, libraries, lists etc.

and you can use, .net Client Object model for that. Here, you don't require to sharepoint in client machine where your application is running.

You can take ref:
http://shahjinesh11.wordpress.com/2012/06/14/net-managed-client-object-model-fetch-all-webs-libraries-items/

Answer (score 2):

I would not recommend that you try and use the CSOM to try and complete this task since you will require data beyond the scope of the security boundaries.

You can likely get most if not all of the info via the provided web services.

If you have access to the servers, I would recommend that you handle it with PowerShell though since that will give you the most robust capabilities and it is typically easier to export the results.  My team has build a number of scripts that can basically document a farm including the details you stated above.